# REGEXP: get the contents of a PHP variable, the assignation itself. Specifically, searching variables with SQL queries

Tags: php, regex, variables, variable-assignment

I think I'm going crazy with this...

I've tried a lot of combinations and I can't get with the good one.

I need to find all the SQL queries in a PHP code after having read it with a `file_get_contents()`.

Of course, all those queries are variable assignations like:

```
$sql1 = "
  SELECT *
  FROM users u
  WHERE u.name LIKE '%".$name."%' AND ... ;
";
```

or

```
$sql2 = "
  SELECT *
  FROM users u
  WHERE u.id = ".$user_id;
```

or

```
$sql3 = '
  SELECT *
  FROM users u
  ORDER BY u.surname1 DESC
'; //this query blablabla.......
```

So you can see that there are many factors to take in account for PHP variables.

First I've tried with an approximation based on getting the variable itself combined with the getting it's content...

I've tried to find specific words from SQL in a regex pattern too...

Whatever...

I don't know how to do it.

1. Getting all the variable and it's assignation, grouping the assignation and after it, looping through matches searching for special SQL words (that's what I've right now, but it doesn't work cause assignation regex part).
2. Directly searching for a SQL queries with a good regex?

PHP variables (specifically strings), contains partially concatenations with other variables, double and single quoted strings, comments at the end of ";" or in the middle...

So what can I do?

So far, that's my variable regex part:

```
$regex_variable = '\\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\s*[\+\-\*\/\%\.\&\|\^\<\>]*=\s*';
```

Which I concatenate with $regex_sql which I've tried different forms:

```
//$regex_sql = '(["\'])(.*?)\2\s*;';
//$regex_sql = '(["\'])([^;]*?)\2\s*;';
//$regex_sql = '(?<!")\b\w+\b|(?<=")\b[^"]+';
//$regex_sql = '([^;]+)(?<=["\']);(?!["\'])';
//$regex_sql = '(.*?;)[^\\$]*';
```

None of those correctly works.

Can you help me please? I'm sure the best approximation it's getting all the variable itself, and after it, testing the assignation for containing some special SQL words like SELECT, WHERE, UNION, ORDER, ...

So much thanks in advance!

Mark.

**edit:**

To add that of course, variables with queries could have any kind of form. Those from above are just simple examples.

We're talking about things such:

```
$s = 'insert into tabletest(a,b,c) values('asd','r32r32','fdfdf')';
```

or

```
$where = 'where a=2';
$sql="select distinct * from test ".$where;
```

or

```
$a = '
select *
from users
left outer join ...
inner join ...
left join ...
where ...
group by ...
having ...
order by ...
limit ...
...
';
```

or

...

Imagine a lot of programmers, creating queries inside the code, anyone doing it at their own way... :\

I've to get ALL of them. At least, maximise the results... ^^'

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the [PHP Tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) - you can use it to tokenize your source (i.e. parse it so it is easier to comprehend) then you can look through the tokens for strings and variables that match your requirements, knowing that each token `;` ends a line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for :

```
preg_match_all('/\$.*?=(.*?)(?<=[\'"]);/s', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[1];
```

This will have all the assignments(*assignations*) stored in $result. I tested it with all your samples.

Sorry if you wanted something else.

**Explanation :**

```
"
\$         # Match the character “\$” literally
.          # Match any single character
   *?         # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
=          # Match the character “=” literally
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   .          # Match any single character
      *?         # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
)
(?<=       # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   ['\"]       # Match a single character present in the list “'\"”
)
;          # Match the character “;” literally
"
```